# HTML Container not fully taking its contents and two containers not in block

Tags: html, css

I want these two containers to be seperate and the `background-color` to take up the entire contents of the container.

Currently they seem to be not taking up the entire contents and overlap onto each other.

I have tried to apply `display: block` to make them seperate but that doesn't work and in regards to the `background-color`, I can't seem to identify the issue.

```css
.commonItem {
  border-image-source: linear-gradient(25deg, #7e848a 15%, #cfcfcf);
  background-image: radial-gradient(#d0d0d0 0%, #6d7071 100%);
}

.handmadeItem {
  border-image-source: linear-gradient(25deg, #008a09 15%, #9eef00);
  background-image: radial-gradient(#5bad03 0%, #01700a 100%);
}

.sturdyItem {
  border-image-source: linear-gradient(25deg, #0063c5 15%, #00efec);
  background-image: radial-gradient(#3dc7ff 0%, #0059a1 100%);
}

.qualityItem {
  background-image: radial-gradient(#d27bf4 0%, #7907a5 100%);
  border-image-source: linear-gradient(25deg, #8037d7 15%, #df2cef);
}

.fineItem {
  border-image-source: linear-gradient(25deg, #df7241 15%, #f6c87c);
  background-image: radial-gradient(#fb9625 0%, #875134 100%);
}

.itemImage {
  width: 100%;
}

.itemContainer {
  height: 106px;
  width: 106px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  border-image-slice: 20;
  border-width: 4px;
  border-style: solid;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  float: left;
}

.itemDetails {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
  width: 100%;
}

.itemName {
  background: rgba(0, 7, 36, 0.5);
  padding: 2px 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}

.itemPrice {
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #000724;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1px 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  color: white;
}

.itemPrice img {
  width: 1.5em;
  padding-right: 0.3rem;
  display: block;
}

.itemShopDaily {
  background-color: red;
  display: block;
}

.itemShopWeekly {
  background-color: green;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="itemShopDaily">
  <div class="containerTitle">Daily Items</div>
  <div class="itemContainer fineItem">
    <img src="URL" class="itemImage">
    <div class="itemDetails">
      <div class="itemName">Sample</div>
      <div class="itemPrice">
        <img src="https://cdn.thetrackernetwork.com/cdn/trackernetwork/3C7Avbucks.png" />
        <span>2,000</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="itemContainer fineItem">
    <img src="URL" class="itemImage">
    <div class="itemDetails">
      <div class="itemName">Sample</div>
      <div class="itemPrice">
        <img src="https://cdn.thetrackernetwork.com/cdn/trackernetwork/3C7Avbucks.png" />
        <span>2,000</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="itemContainer fineItem">
    <img src="URL" class="itemImage">
    <div class="itemDetails">
      <div class="itemName">Sample</div>
      <div class="itemPrice">
        <img src="https://cdn.thetrackernetwork.com/cdn/trackernetwork/3C7Avbucks.png" />
        <span>2,000</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="itemShopWeekly">
  <div class="containerTitle" style="margin-top: 5px;">Weekly Items</div>
  <div class="itemContainer qualityItem">
    <img src="URL" class="itemImage">
    <div class="itemDetails">
      <div class="itemName">Sample</div>
      <div class="itemPrice">
        <img src="https://cdn.thetrackernetwork.com/cdn/trackernetwork/3C7Avbucks.png" />
        <span>2,000</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="itemContainer qualityItem">
    <img src="URL" class="itemImage">
    <div class="itemDetails">
      <div class="itemName">Sample</div>
      <div class="itemPrice">
        <img src="https://cdn.thetrackernetwork.com/cdn/trackernetwork/3C7Avbucks.png" />
        <span>2,000</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="itemContainer qualityItem">
    <img src="URL" class="itemImage">
    <div class="itemDetails">
      <div class="itemName">Sample</div>
      <div class="itemPrice">
        <img src="https://cdn.thetrackernetwork.com/cdn/trackernetwork/3C7Avbucks.png" />
        <span>2,000</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Working JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gk3utjhr/
Working on website: http://fortniteprosnipes.x10.bz/

Comment: Try to shorten your code by removing unnecessary lines of code, specify your problem, and tell us what you've done, and doesn't work so that we can help you out... Oh, and welcome to SOF Community!

Answer (score 0):

You need a clearfix on your float containers.

```css
.commonItem {
  border-image-source: linear-gradient(25deg, #7e848a 15%, #cfcfcf);
  background-image: radial-gradient(#d0d0d0 0%, #6d7071 100%);
}

.handmadeItem {
  border-image-source: linear-gradient(25deg, #008a09 15%, #9eef00);
  background-image: radial-gradient(#5bad03 0%, #01700a 100%);
}

.sturdyItem {
  border-image-source: linear-gradient(25deg, #0063c5 15%, #00efec);
  background-image: radial-gradient(#3dc7ff 0%, #0059a1 100%);
}

.qualityItem {
  background-image: radial-gradient(#d27bf4 0%, #7907a5 100%);
  border-image-source: linear-gradient(25deg, #8037d7 15%, #df2cef);
}

.fineItem {
  border-image-source: linear-gradient(25deg, #df7241 15%, #f6c87c);
  background-image: radial-gradient(#fb9625 0%, #875134 100%);
}

.itemImage {
  width: 100%;
}

.itemContainer {
  height: 106px;
  width: 106px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  border-image-slice: 20;
  border-width: 4px;
  border-style: solid;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  float: left;
}

.itemDetails {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
  width: 100%;
}

.itemName {
  background: rgba(0, 7, 36, 0.5);
  padding: 2px 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}

.itemPrice {
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #000724;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1px 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  color: white;
}

.itemPrice img {
  width: 1.5em;
  padding-right: 0.3rem;
  display: block;
}

.itemShopDaily {
  background-color: red;
  display: block;
}

.itemShopWeekly {
  background-color: green;
  display: block;
}

.clearfix:after {
  content: " ";
  /* Older browser do not support empty content */
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="itemShopDaily clearfix">
  <div class="containerTitle">Daily Items</div>
  <div class="itemContainer fineItem">
    <img src="URL" class="itemImage">
    <div class="itemDetails">
      <div class="itemName">Sample</div>
      <div class="itemPrice">
        <img src="https://cdn.thetrackernetwork.com/cdn/trackernetwork/3C7Avbucks.png" />
        <span>2,000</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="itemContainer fineItem">
    <img src="URL" class="itemImage">
    <div class="itemDetails">
      <div class="itemName">Sample</div>
      <div class="itemPrice">
        <img src="https://cdn.thetrackernetwork.com/cdn/trackernetwork/3C7Avbucks.png" />
        <span>2,000</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="itemContainer fineItem">
    <img src="URL" class="itemImage">
    <div class="itemDetails">
      <div class="itemName">Sample</div>
      <div class="itemPrice">
        <img src="https://cdn.thetrackernetwork.com/cdn/trackernetwork/3C7Avbucks.png" />
        <span>2,000</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="itemShopWeekly clearfix">
  <div class="containerTitle" style="margin-top: 5px;">Weekly Items</div>
  <div class="itemContainer qualityItem">
    <img src="URL" class="itemImage">
    <div class="itemDetails">
      <div class="itemName">Sample</div>
      <div class="itemPrice">
        <img src="https://cdn.thetrackernetwork.com/cdn/trackernetwork/3C7Avbucks.png" />
        <span>2,000</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="itemContainer qualityItem">
    <img src="URL" class="itemImage">
    <div class="itemDetails">
      <div class="itemName">Sample</div>
      <div class="itemPrice">
        <img src="https://cdn.thetrackernetwork.com/cdn/trackernetwork/3C7Avbucks.png" />
        <span>2,000</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="itemContainer qualityItem">
    <img src="URL" class="itemImage">
    <div class="itemDetails">
      <div class="itemName">Sample</div>
      <div class="itemPrice">
        <img src="https://cdn.thetrackernetwork.com/cdn/trackernetwork/3C7Avbucks.png" />
        <span>2,000</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You should consider revising your approach to this layout to use Flexbox instead.

```css
.container {
  padding: 10px;
}

.container.daily {
  background: red;
}

.container.weekly {
  background: green;
}

.container-title {
  margin: 0;
}

.items {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.item {
  height: 106px;
  width: 106px;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  display: flex;
}

.item-inner {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 5px;
}

.daily .item-inner {
  background: #7907a5;
}

.weekly .item-inner {
  background: #fb9625;
}
```

```html
<div class="container daily">
  <h5 class="container-title">Daily Items</h5>
  <div class="items">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="item-inner"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="item-inner"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="item-inner"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container weekly">
  <h5 class="container-title">Weekly Items</h5>
  <div class="items">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="item-inner"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="item-inner"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="item-inner"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: How would I go about aligning all the containers inside the parent div to the center?

Comment: @FortniteMatcher I've updated the 2nd snippet to center each `.item`

Comment: Let me know if you need any more help.